# SSH and Ethereum node

Tags: ethereum

I have a node **(virtual machine 1)** with open port for SSH and keys are in the keystore, can another virtual machine (without a node and keys) in same network transact using the node and keys in the virtual machine 1 by accessing a website that use web3.js ?

e.g. Like accessing a METAMASK custom RPC pointing to localhost in the VM2 >> but the transaction is in VM1

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure, but this is really **dangerous**! Because you basically expose your keys to the outside world and this is a honeypot for script-kiddies to find your exposed RPC endpoints.

Better way is to create the transaction at VM2 and use VM1 to broadcast it, there is no web3.js required at all. Just expose the Websockets- or HTTP-JSONRPC endpoints to the web. **Note**, you should only expose safe APIs.

For Parity-Ethereum, VM1 config would look like this:

```
parity --jsonrpc-port 53545           \
       --jsonrpc-interface 133.3.3.37 \ # your public IP of VM1
       --jsonrpc-apis safe            \ # only expose safe APIs
       --jsonrpc-hosts 242.42.42.42   \ # the IP (or hostname) of VM2
```

This way you can create the transaction at VM2 and broadcast it using VM1 [raw transaction](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-eth-module#eth_sendrawtransaction):

```
curl --data '{"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction","params":["0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST 133.3.3.37:53545
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How is it dangerous? VM1 and Vm2 will be in same private network (infra network). VM2 will transact using localhost and forwarding it to VM1. Can you please explain more why it is dangerous as --rpcAddrr will point to localhost not 0.0.0.0

Comment: The idea is to have one node only that the can be used by other VM in the network (infra private network)